# Designing linear systems to respond to particular kinds of oscillations

Tags: optimization, dynamical-systems, control-theory

Say that I have a linear system which is being perturbed by an **oscillating** signal of a single frequency, of the form 
$$
\dot{\vec{x}}(t) = A\vec{x} + B \sin(\alpha t),
$$
where $B$ is a vector of 1s and 0s. I want to find a matrix $A$ that will dampen or eliminate the signal, such that 
$$
\int_0^T \| x(t) \|^2 dt
$$
is as small as possible.

**Does any analytical method exist to find such an $A$?**

Comment: what is $x(t)^2$? Since $x(t)$ is a vector, I guess you mean $x(t)^{\top}x(t)$.

Comment: Would you be willing to let $T$ go to infinity? :)

Comment: a) Thanks for the catch - I'm apparently still sleep walking.
b) Yes, that would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is by no means a complete solution but maybe it takes you somewhere. If you take the Laplace transform of both sides and assume $x(0)$ to be the zero vector, then you get
$$X(s) = (sI-A)^{-1}B\frac{\alpha}{s^2+\alpha^2}$$

Then I invoke Parseval's Theorem and write
$$\int_0^{\infty}x(t)^{\top}x(t)dt=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\alpha}{-\omega^2+\alpha^2}\right)^2\|(j\omega I-A)^{-1}B\|^2d\omega$$

This clearly has something to do with the controllability properties of $(A,B)$ but I haven't figured it out yet. I'll take another look at it tomorrow with a fresh set of eyes.

Comment: This looks cool so far - the Laplace transform is a good idea. I look forward to seeing where you get tomorrow!